# Is there a way to make $watch behave like $watchCollection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-watch

I am using a third party library that uses `$watch` to watch a collection.  Unfortunately I cannot change that to use `$watchCollection` and specifying a deep watch on the `$watch` gives me performance issues.

What is the most performant way I can update an item in my array whilst triggering the `$watch`?

I have tried this but it didnt work.  I expect because the list reference hasnt changed.

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    // IF we need to update then do this:
    list[i] = newItem;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. So, you have `$scope.$watch(...)` code in file which you cannot edit, and you want it to behave differently without editing this code? Not possible. The solution may be possibly to copy the array each time it should be modified. Or it may be not. The question lacks the necessary details. What is 'my array'? How it is used? [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is needed.

Comment: list = angular.copy(list) -- what else can it be... But you know usually watch is done on purpose, so better tell details -- may be you just missed some event or another way to trigger change.

Comment: I'm using angular-ui-google-maps.  They use a `$watch` rather than `$watchCollection` for change detection on an array with `true` passed in for deep watch.. If I disable deep watch (for performance) I couldn't update the list.. I did try `angular.copy` too but it didn't work. Ill try again!